# Android apk update for same app, can I preserve data?

Tags: android, database, react-native, apk, version

If I installed app (named "MyApp") version 1 from apk1, now I have apk2 for version 2 of the same app (MyApp). Without uninstalling MyApp, I plan to execute apk2. Is it possible to replace the UI, and preserve all previous data in local db (on phone)?

If possible, please explain how I should configure apk2 in code (is it AndroidManifest.xml or other files?), to tell the phone that "This apk is version 2 of MyApp. If MyApp exists on phone, please replace its UI, but preserve its previous data."?

P.S. I use React Native, with limited knowledge about pure Android development. I'm not talking about updating an Android app via any "App Store".

Comment: If you don't tell otherwise, application data will be preserved when you upgrade.

Comment: See: [Testing an adb update, versus install?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8962226/295004) As long as the [application id](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set_the_application_id) and signing key are the same the app should update.